# PHP PDO Prepared Update Statement where =

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE site_users SET users_email_verified = :users_email_verified WHERE users_email = :users_email AND users_password = :users_password and users_email_verified = :users_email_not_verified ");

$stmt->bindParam(':users_email_not_verified', $users_email_not_verified,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':users_email_verified', $users_email_verified,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':users_email',$_GET["email"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':users_password',$_GET["token"],PDO::PARAM_STR);

$users_email_verified = 1;
$users_email_not_verified = 0;

// The next 2 lines are supposed to count total number of rows effected
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo count($result);
$stmt->execute();
```

What I am trying here is, I want to update `users_email_verified` row, where emaii, password match the valies + where `users_email_verified` is set to 0 (not to 1).

0 = Not verified
1 = Verified.

But nothing gets updated in my code, while it is supposed to.

`echo count($result);` always echo `0`.

No errors are being shown. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: You need to execute before you can fetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You need to ***execute first*** (`$stmt->execute()`) and then ***fetch count*** (`$stmt->rowCount()`).

2.`UPDATE` query don't return records after successful execution, it just return number of affected rows. So use `rowCount()` to get number of affected rows.

***Check below correct code:-***

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE site_users SET users_email_verified = :users_email_verified WHERE users_email = :users_email AND users_password = :users_password and users_email_verified = :users_email_not_verified ");

$users_email_verified = 1;
$users_email_not_verified = 0;

$stmt->bindParam(':users_email_not_verified', $users_email_not_verified,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':users_email_verified', $users_email_verified,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':users_email',$_GET["email"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':users_password',$_GET["token"],PDO::PARAM_STR);



// The next 2 lines are supposed to count total number of rows effected

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $result;
```